# Unfamiliar call a function which is in square bracket

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I'm a fresh man in Javascript and vue.js. Recently, I began to use Vue to build a management system of our company, so I read some code from internet and learn how to use it.
Here are fragment of code which I can't understand. How could I define a function in square bracket?

The code is use for vuex.

```
//mutation-types.js
export const ADD_TOTAL_TIME = 'ADD_TOTAL_TIME'
export const DEC_TOTAL_TIME = 'DEC_TOTAL_TIME'
export const SAVE_PLAN = 'SAVE_PLAN'
export const DELETE_PLAN = 'DELETE_PLAN'

//mutation.js
import * as types from './mutation-types'
export default {
  [types.ADD_TOTAL_TIME] (state, time) {
    state.totalTime = state.totalTime + time
  },
  [types.DEC_TOTAL_TIME] (state, time) {
    state.totalTime = state.totalTime - time
  },
  [types.SAVE_PLAN] (state, plan) {
    const avatar = 'https://sfault-avatar.b0.upaiyun.com/147/223/147223148-573297d0913c5_huge256'
    state.list.push(
      Object.assign({name: 'Jack', avatar: avatar}, plan)
    )
  },
  [types.DELETE_PLAN] (state, idx) {
    state.list.splice(idx, 1)
  }
}
```

[Define functions name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72bi5.png)
[Function Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goRlZ.png)

Comment: Computed property names. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Computed_property_names

Answer (score 1):

These are computed property names, see [Object initializer: Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and [Method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Computed_property_names) for details.